# cakephp 2.3 link tag with rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed'

Tags: html, cakephp

I need to generate the following html tag with cakephp 2.3  Please give any help to generate it. There is an image which I have place in `img` folder it comes as href attribute value.

```
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
```

I try with different of option with meta but I can not resolve the image path issue.

Comment: you can generate it with a helper, or you can write `<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="/img/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">` directly in your html/view/layout and move on.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo $this->Html->meta(array(
    'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
    'sizes' => '144x144',
    'link' => '/img/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build any Html tags by `HtmlHelper::tag`: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::tag